# Vector transforms

Tags: vector-spaces, transformational-geometry

I have used

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 0}] 
/. G_Line :> {Red, GeometricTransformation[G, TranslationTransform[{Sqrt[10], 0}]]} 
/. L_Line :> {Red, GeometricTransformation[L, ScalingTransform[{1, 0.5}]]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, Sqrt[10]}, {0, 5}}]
```

in *Mathematica* to plot

[image]

Please excuse my ignorance, but how would I find out the mathematics behind these vector transforms?

## Important note:

I have cross posted this on Mathematica Stack Exchange also - please let me know if this is not accepted practice & I shall delete accordingly.